# Oracle Forms 6i Resolve LOV code

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have a LOV with two columns one is code and the other is description. I know that text items have a property which says validate from list however my code field and description field are display items. We do not want to force the user to click on a button to show the LOV. In the pre-form trigger i am setting a default value in the code field.

I would like to get/resolve the code to its description from the list without having to do a select from the database. Does anyone know of a way to get this done?

Comment: If you put a default value on it, you probably now the description at this moment already, so why you need to resolve it.

Comment: Please post the `pre-form trigger` code.

Comment: @Annjawn the pre-form just has :code := 10;

Comment: @nigthfox79 I set a default value in it however i need to tab out of the :code field for the item to resolve or validate against the list i am setting the value in the pre-form and not able to access this field when the form fires. The both :code and :description fields are display items.

Comment: If you know that `:code:=10` then you might as well know what the description of the that code is, so you can put `:desc=<description>` if your fields are display only no one will be able to edit that anyways, unless the value of `:code` is determined based on some rule before the pre-form trigger fires in which case both the values will be different everytime..

Comment: @Annjawn i unerstand what you're saying but is that a true reflection of what is in the list? What if the description changes in the database then that will not be a true reflection of what is contained in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had also this very same problem. There might not be a solution to retrieve the label column from record group in the runtime.

But you could do this:

1. Store the record group query somewhere (package header or DB column).
2. Populate your record group with query in the runtime.
3. Create DB function which takes query and key value as parameters. The function would then return description of the key value (use dynamic SQL, execute immediate / dbms_sql).
4. Use the function in the POST-QUERY trigger:

`:block.item_description := your_new_function(l_query, :block.item_value);`